# how to get UsageStats data like this and also view like this?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, listview, usagestatsmanager

*i am get some data like this *

```
UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService("usagestats");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    long start = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<UsageStats> stats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, start, end);
    //Map<String,UsageStats> stats =usageStatsManager.queryAndAggregateUsageStats( start,  end);



    for (int i = 0; i < stats.size() ; i++)
    {
        Log.e(TAG,"<<<<"+i+">>>>"+"--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Log.e(TAG,"Package Name =  "+stats.get(i).getPackageName());
        printt("First Time Stamp =  ",stats.get(i).getFirstTimeStamp());
        printt("Last Time Stamp =  ",stats.get(i).getLastTimeStamp());
        printt("Last Time Used =  ",stats.get(i).getLastTimeUsed());
        printt("Total Time Used in foreground =  ",stats.get(i).getTotalTimeInForeground());

    }
```

*but how i calculate and show like this and how to i get app start time and end time from this available data*

[image: *show usage of app *]

Comment: DO not combine multiple question into one .

Comment: you just tell me how to get usagestate data like this

Comment: For calculated fields, you have to parse the stats data and calculate  them manually

Comment: i know that but my question is how i calculate start time and Edn time of all app @NitinSingh